# usage example of PropertyResourceBundle(Reader reader) in Java6

Tags: java, localization, internationalization

I have multiple messages.properties files in utf-8 encoded files(messages_en_US.properties, messages_fr.properties,...). Among these properties files, I have some for Asian languages. This means, characters cannot be represented in ISO-8859-1 encoding and must be represented by Unicode Escapes. I do not want to do this. Based on documentation from link below, if I use the constructor which takes a Reader, it does not have that limitation.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html

But, if I do use this constructor, I am losing the functionality that determines the correct properties file based on Locale.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be instantiating PropertyResourceBundle directly.  Use [ResourceBundle.getBundle()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

Also take a look at the second example under [ResourceBundle.Control](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html) for how to load alternate formats while still using the resolution hierarchy.  The example is for loading XML properties, but should be adaptable to use a UTF-8 encoded InputStream.

Comment: So, ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("myMessages", locale).

Comment: But, If I do the above, I am stuck with ISO-8859-1 encoding. My asian char set will not be supported. So, how do I make use of the Reader?

Comment: I've edited my post to include a pointer to `ResourceBundle.Control`, which you should be able to use.

Comment: With that Control thing, it could be made to work. But why do they need to make this so difficult? Why is there no Control subclass for example that loads property files using a user-specified encoding. No one wants to have to native2ascii them in the build process or write extra code just to be able to load them in another encoding.

Comment: Agreed, it's _much_ more complex than it should be.

Answer (score 0):

It seems they really want you to still use native2ascii. :-(

This way, you can encode your Asian characters as \uxxxx sequences. The ResourceBundle mechanism can load them in this format.

What we do is that we edit the property files in UTF-8, and the build script runs native2ascii on them.

Seeing that Java6 finally supports different encodings for Properties when you load them manually, it would be nice if that support trickled down (up?) to the other pieces that build on properties, such as resource bundles.